# React incorrect update with useState and || operator

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a search bar with a nice drop-down menu to let the user know what he could do.
The drop-down menu require only one trigger to be display. (I represented them by 2 input nodes)

```js
function SearchBar() {

    const [focus1, setFocus1] = useState(false);
    const [focus2, setFocus2] = useState(false);
    return <>
        <input onFocus={(event) => setFocus1(true)}
               onBlur={(event) => setFocus1(false)} />
        <input onFocus={(event) => setFocus2(true)}
               onBlur={(event) => setFocus2(false)} />
        {focus1 || focus2 ? <p>drop-down with other onClick actions</p> : null}
    </>;
}
```

The problem is that react re-render the `<p>` node when I switch from one input to the other one. The normal behaviour should not update the node tree as the content is identical.

How can I avoid the React to re-render this node ?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you switch focus from one input to the next one, either one of your focus state is always true, hence it is expected (since the `<p>` node is rendered conditionally using `||` logic). you can monitor the focus states by using `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log
      ('focus1', focus1)
  }, [focus1])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log
      ('focus2', focus2)
  }, [focus2])
```